# define peak at three-way non-linear interaction

Tags: r, interaction, longitudinal

we have a significant three-way quadratic interaction (all 3 continuous variables) and now would like to define the "tipping point". The Johnson-Neyman technique only allows for two-way interactions. Any suggestions how we can calculate the peak?

here is some random data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame( SID=sample(1:150,400,replace=TRUE),age=sample(50:70,400,replace=TRUE), sex=sample(c("Male","Female"),200, replace=TRUE),time= seq(0.7, 6.2, length.out=400), AM =rnorm(mean=-0.8, sd=0.08, n=400),DMD=rnorm(mean=1.4, sd=0.2, n=400), MEC =rnorm(mean=0, sd=2, n=400))  
mydata$time <- as.numeric(mydata$time)
```

Here is the lme with the quadratic 3-way interaction:

```
model <- lme(MEC ~ age+sex+AM*DMD*time+I((AM*DMD*time)^2), random=~time|SID, data=mydata); summary(model)
```

I now would like to know at which intersection between AM and DMD occurs the peak / trough. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as this is more of a method/algorithm question than a problem with code/programming.

Comment: Ok! I posted it at CrossValidated. Thanks!